German equivalent of "Under the weather"
In english, we say "Under the weather", when we are sick or slightly unwell. However, is there an idiomatic way of saying the same phrase in German? I do understand that most idiomatic phrases do not have direct translations, due to the various socio-cultural factors. However which idiomatic phrase would be the closest to "Under the weather" in german.

Where I live, we say "(etwas) angeschlagen" or "(gesundheitlich) nicht ganz auf der Höhe".

Ich bin etwas angeschlagen und mache heute früher Feierabend.


Oh ok, alright! Are there any other ways of saying it tho? Do any of them relate to "weather" or is it not a thing in german?

There's the adjective wetterfühlig for slight headaches et al that come and go with the weather.

To me being "wetterfühlig" is a general tendency of a person to feel pain in certain weather conditions, I wouldn't use it to express an acute condition. But I agree, it's the only expression I can think of in this context that has to do with weather.

Maybe

jemandem ist unwohl: Mir ist unwohl. Ich fürchte, bei mir ist eine Grippe im Anflug.
jemand ist angegriffen: Thalia Drummond sah angegriffen aus. Dunkle Ringe lagen unter ihren Augen, und sie machte einen müden, abgespannten Eindruck. (Edgar Wallace translated to German)
jemand ist unpässlich: [often with the idea 'can't show up for work or an appointment] Carina ließ sich für den Ausflug entschuldigen; es hieß, sie sei unpässlich.
jemand ist nicht in der besten Verfassung: Er hatte ein wildes Wochenende hinter sich und war dementsprechend nicht in der besten Verfassung.
jemand kränkelt: Seit zwei Monaten kränkelt sie und meldet sich immer wieder für ein oder zwei Tage auf der Arbeit ab.
jemand ist nicht gut zurecht [coll., regional]: Ich bin heut nicht gut zurecht. Kalt ist mir und alles tut weh. (facebook)
jemand ist nicht gut dabei: [coll., regional] Er klagt nicht, dass es ihm schlecht geht, aber jeder sieht, dass er nicht gut dabei ist.
jemand ist etwas wacklig auf den Beinen [= "schwach", fig., coll., regional, could also be interpreted literally] Sie fühlte sich mit ihren leichten Kreislaufproblemen wacklig auf den Beinen, war aber ansonsten bei guter Laune.

